# Bootstrap jumbotron automatically changes size with amount of content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have the following view page code (uses codeigniter, bootstrap and PHP). I have given only the code between `<body>` and `</body>` as well as the CSS.

```
<div class="row">  
  <?php echo $navbar; ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div  class="container">
      <div id="tasks" class="col-md-2">
        <?php echo $task_set; ?>
      </div>        
      <div id="replaceable" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
        <div id="current_view">
          <?php if(isset($current_view)) echo $current_view   ;?>
        </div>
        <div id="pass_chg_form" style="display:none;">
          <?php echo $pass_change_form; ?>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
  <?php echo $footer; ?>
</div>

<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editArea' ); //replace text area with ckeeditor
</script>
```

**My css is:**

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
.jumbotron {
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
#tasks {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#replaceable {
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:100px
}
```

The problem is that the jumbotron changes size with changing the amount of content in the page. How do I get a jumbotron that will occupy full height of the containing element no matter how much content is there (i.e Jumbotron height should extend up to navbar and footer no matter what)?

Comment: So is the "navbar" and "footer" positioned fixed to the top and bottom of the window"? If so, then you can use absolute positioning. If not, then the "jumbotron" parent element (the .row div) will need relative positioning, and the child "jumobtron" div will need a set height to prevent the height shifting.

Comment: Yes, my navbar and footer are fixed to the top and bottom of the window.You said absolute positioning.Did you mean something like .jumbotron {
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
} for <div class="jumbotron">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, if the `navbar` and `footer` divs are positioned fixed, then you can apply your css like:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .navbar {
        color: white;
        background: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 0;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .footer {
        color: white;
        background: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: auto;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .jumbotron {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 50px;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 2px solid red;
        border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

**EXAMPLE:** [See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jwjkbhaq/)